# AngularJS ng-if has a strange delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

[image: problem with delay]

On the image, you can see that there are loading spinners next to the numbers.

The DOM element that shows the spinner has `ng-if = "gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState == 'loading'"`.

The DOM element that shows the number has `ng-if = "gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState == 'loaded'"`.

Code is below:

```
<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" style="font-size: 12px;" ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState=='loading'"></i>
<span ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState=='failed'">-</span>
<span ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState=='loaded'">{{ gridItem.content_score }}</span>
```

When loading ends, first the number shows and after a small delay loading spinner disappears. But for an instant both of them appears at the same time and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

I tried to wrap `<i..` inside of a wrapper element and moved to `ng-if` to there. And it worked. Like this:

```
<span ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState==='loading'"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></span>
<span ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState==='failed'">-</span>
<span ng-if="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState==='loaded'">{{ gridItem.combined_frequency }}</span>
```

Comment: I can confirm, almost a year later, this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause could be ngAnimate if you're using that module (grasping at straws, but that's caused me issues in the past).

Regardless, in your situation it probably makes more sense to use a switch:

```
<span ng-switch="gridItem.contentScoreLoadingState">
  <span ng-switch-when="loading"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></span>
  <span ng-switch-when="failed">-</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="loaded">{{ gridItem.content_score }}</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The problem was that I placed the ng-if directly on the icon, The below solution worked.